# Wordpress plugins to create a web submission website

Tags: web-development, php, wordpress

I am a newbie wordpress developer. So, I need suggestions from experienced developers here. I want to create a Web Directory submission website like **allfreethings.com** using wordpress. What are the plugins I will need to create it from scratch?

Comment: Could help me with this..?

Comment: Steve, if I could I already had done so, sorry.